# How to import e-mail from Opera to Thunderbird

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, opera, email-client

I have the mail folder of an Opera (12, Linux) installation long gone, with 3.6GiB of e-mail data. Even Opera Mail is not available anymore, so I don't think I have a chance to directly open those e-mails. Many of them are also not on the server anymore, and two of the e-mail accounts have since been terminated.

I'm trying to set up Thunderbird, on openSUSE Tumbleweed, to use those e-mail accounts and give me access to my old mails.
Usually Thunderbird offers to import mails from other installed e-mail software but as I said, Opera is not on this system, and I don't seem to be able to get hold of Opera Mail anymore.
This rules out the use of the [most popular method of moving mail over from Opera](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_from_Opera), which includes exporting the mail from Opera first (should have known before I nuked that installation...)

I have also found the [ImportExportTools extension](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) for Thunderbird, but I tested it on a very small subset of the messages, and apparently it generates a new folder for every .mbs file in the Opera mail store. This is pretty awful since Opera switched to storing every single message in a separate file at some point, and one of the accounts has about 20k e-mails in it...

I guess I could write a script which concatenates all mbox files for a single account, and then import that, but I was wondering if I'm overlooking a better way. Maybe there's even something which would let me keep the folders/views I had set up in Opera (my goodness, were those things handy!)?

Any ideas? I'd be okay to move to a different email client if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oldversion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/opera) has version 12 available for Windows. I'd install it on a Windows box, bring in your files, then export from Opera.